# C-y doesn't yank in emacs under tmux

Tags: emacs, tmux

### **Update**

What's happening is that whenever I kill some text, it gets added to the `kill-ring` followed by an extra `""`. Then `C-y` just inserts the `""`. So the question is where is the extra `""` coming from?

### **Original Question**

I'm running `emacs` under `tmux`, and I can't get `C-y` (or even `M-x yank`) to insert content from the `kill-ring`. I do see `Mark set` in the minibuffer, which is normal behavior for `yank`; I just don't see anything getting yanked. I also see that `""` gets added to the `kill-ring` each time I hit `C-y`.

I know that `C-y` is getting received by `emacs` by looking at the output of `M-x view-lossage`, and I know that `C-y` is bound to `yank` by looking at the keybindings with `C-h b`. Moreover, running `M-x yank` directly gives the exact same results.

When I repeat the experiment outside of `tmux`, it works as expected. For what it's worth, if I repeat the experiment with `screen` instead of `tmux`, `C-y` works as expected.

Some more details are that within `tmux`, I have tried running `emacs` with `TERM=xterm-256color` and `TERM=screen-256color` with the same result. Setting `xterm-keys on` or `xterm-keys off` in `tmux` doesn't seem to matter either. I've been closing every `tmux` session between each permutation I try, to make sure that my `.tmux.conf` is getting re-processed (And I know it is because other changes in my `.tmux.conf` do have an effect.)
In fact, I can even comment out my entire `.tmux.conf`, with the same result.

Also, I've tried it in both `iTerm2` and `Terminal.app` (I'm on a mac), again with the same result.

So, I feel like I am at a dead-end here. Any ideas on how to better debug this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally tracked it down to some code I had copied into my `emacs` `init.el` to allow copy-and-paste from my OSX clipboard. If I remove that code from my `init.el`, `C-y` works fine under `tmux`. (The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/267162) -- it worked great until I decided to try out `tmux`!) I'm still not sure exactly what the problem is, but it's easy to believe that it would affect the behavior of `C-y`.

Comment: You can use my [`reattach-to-user-namespace` program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/) to access the pasteboard from inside *tmux*.